# How do I determine which AudioContext constructor to use in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api

I'm using the HTML5 web audio API, and I'm trying to dynamically determine which AudioContext constructor to use via

```
var constructor = AudioContext || webkitAudioContext;
var context = new constructor();
```

However, with this code, Safari quips:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AudioContext
```

For starters, I didn't even know that `ReferenceError`s exist in javascript, since undefined variables by default take on the `undefined` value. Safari's implementation of javascript apparently differs in big ways from that of Chrome, even though both use webkit engines ...

How do I determine which constructor to use without triggering this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try window.AudioContext instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DLeh, the answer is correct. It doesn't go into the reason for the error, but it says how to avoid it. The reason being that an undefined variable reference is not the same as an undefined object property. This behavior is not Safari-specific.

Comment: Thanks! `window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;` works.